# Create 2 independent local networks connected to one ISP

Tags: networking, router, internet, isp

My brother lives in the house next to me and I am borrowing him internet. He is using a Vodafone router Sercomm Vox 2.5. For me I bought the same one in the second-hand market and connected it to his router using a RJ45 connector.

It was working OK for me. We had two different wifis but in the end we were in the same network. For example, if he was watching Netflix on tv, I could see in my phone a notification saying there were someone casting in my network.

Now I am renting my house and want to offer free internet to my tenants, and therefore I need to change it so they don't connect to my brother's network. What I think I have to do is to buy another Sercomm router and establish it as an ISP, and then connect it to the 2 routers that will create 2 different networks.

Am I right? Will it work directly or do I need to change something in the router configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a cascade of routers: Router 2 connected via WAN to Router 1's LAN, and then connect router 1's WAN to the internet. Apparently, WAN does not create a connection between local networks, it just transmits internet.

I tried to do it with the Vodafone's router and didn't get it at first chance, and as I needed to do it rapidly, I just bought a Xiaomi Mi 4a for the second network.

Extra notes: With Xiaomi router, speed was limited to ~10MB/S, and Vodafone's was able to get speeds of 20MB/S. So yes, sometimes their routers are not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to do that. You just need to enable NAT on your router.

Your router is probably in bridge mode, which puts everything on the same subnet. If you enable NAT on your router it'll put your router (and everything connected to it) on a different subnet. You won't be able to see your brothers stuff and he won't he able to see yours.

Comment: thank you, but that solution won't allow my brother to have its own network. But looks like you assume my solution is valid, right? I could connect 2 routers to another one that acts like a modem and then define a specific subnet mask for each network.